# Mongoose and postman error in method model.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

[This is the screenshot of my Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBGrs.png)[This is the screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FDHy.png)

```js
app.get("/students/:id",async(req,res)=>{
    try {
         const _id=req.params.id;
         const studentData=await Student.findById(_id);
         console.log(studentData);
         if(!studentData){
             return res.status(404).send();
         }else 
            res.send(studentData);
    }
    catch(err) {
          res.send(err);
    }
});
```

For this id case I am able to find the value in database.
But if I am using model.find({name:name}) as per screenshot ,I am getting some error in postman.Can anyone help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have two conflicting routes, from your code above I see you have a get route for `/student/:id` and from the screenshot you have another get route for `/student/:name` these two routes cannot exist together as express is going to pick the first one you defined.
I suggest changing them to `/student/id/:id` and `/student/name/:name`.